# how i may know if UIPickerView is spinning now or not

Tags: ios

Help me please.

How i may know if UIPickerView is spinning now or not?

In UIPickerViewDelegate i dont find any similar methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Sorry to be late.

As far as I know, the only think you can do to check if your UIPickerView is spinning or not is to look at one of these two methods of UIPickerViewDelegate:

```
– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:
– pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
```

These methods are called when the UIPickerView needs to change the views/labels it shows. That happens whenever you spin it enough to make a new row appear.

Unfortunately, if your UIPickerView has just few rows or if it doesn't spin enough you can miss its movement...